# Can I truly express my thoughts?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language, language

Looking at the Private language argument it occurs to me that Wittgenstein does not really account for the developmental nature of language:

Temporal and spacial separation of Speakers will invariably introduce changes to meaning of words, changes in pronunciation and eventually completely different languages. Which means that within a splinter group an *individual* need to introduce a subtle change to initiate the deviation process. This means that *the individual* conception of the semantics and pronunciation of an word is a (main) agency of change for the common language.

Through the process of maturation an individual will frequently need to change their understanding of common language words. Not only the semantic content, but also emotional connotation and personal preferences are attached to concepts *within* a person's mind. When a concept is invoked by common language interaction the entire individual history of contact with that concept is invoked. These histories are, per concept, unique to individuals.

The implication is that common language is the consensual 'overlap' of individual private languages. This would seem to fall prey to Wittgenstein's stipulation that a private language should *in principal* not be translatable. However, while we may use wildly different mental faculties to 'process' a certain concept, when we even as much as think about communicating it we immediately invoke translation to common language. Therefore *access* to a private language is in principal impossible.

**Is there any philosophers that have argued against the impossibility of a private language and what is their arguments?**

Comment: Not 100% on-topic, but maybe you'll find the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis interesting, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity (or maybe you'll respond to it in a way that you can't precisely put into words)

Comment: You can't, if we assume qualia can't be shared. If they can through telepathy, for example, then telepathy would be sufficient. But not through spoken language.

Comment: @JohnForkosh In support of that we might cite loan words such as 'gestalt' and 'zeitgeist' which would imply that at some point English (speakers) could not frame those concepts while German could. The hypothesis itself indicates a deeper 'cognitive differentiation' precipitated by the superficial 'language differentiation' I presented. - so 110% on-topic. :)

Comment: @rus9384 Interesting consequence of private languages would be the that telepathy could not work from 'mind to mind'; because private languages cannot be translated the common language would still be needed as an interpreter. The best telepathy could do is communicate between the (brain's) speech centers.

Comment: Well, it is not clear. Your green may differ from my green. But what you could want me to experience is your green, not my green. What is a private language then? And no, telepathy could do pretty much, because it is ability to directly affect others' brains, including their sensory cortexes.

Comment: @rus9384 Due to genetic differences and brain plasticity, the brain mechanism for presenting a _perception_ to the consciousness is unique to every person. So accepting the uniqueness of qualia as a function of 'brain' diversity, and considering the experiential and emotional connotations, "my green" may reach your consciousness as "table cloth". Conversely if we accept that images, concepts etc. can be accurately transferred  from mind to mind, then me must admit to a 'universal mind language' that operates 'above' the brain level. This would be a very strong support for Idealism.

Comment: This is not proved. There are plasticity and genetic differences but they are not what you are talking about. It is possible that what you want to transfer to me, my brain simply can't play. But if it can, it will play. I think we need more emprical data, and we'd need to a wait a couple of decades.

Comment: While those are good points they are relying on the idea of meaning that Wittgenstein rejects. There are no "meanings" to change, there is no  "semantic content" to emotionally connote, there are no "concepts within a person's mind", etc., there is only ever fluid use of words in language games. There is no need to "initiate" a deviation or "change" understanding, there is nothing solid to deviate from or change.  And public language is not an 'overlap' of private languages simply because conception of the latter is incoherent. There is nothing privately linguistic to share or not share.

Comment: 1. Unfortunately, no, my friend, because your thoughts are a product of the social system, environment and time in which you live. 2. A person simply does not have his thoughts. 3. If he had them, he would not be able to express them by the means available to him.

Comment: @Conifold Wittgenstein hardly is the center of the universe. Yes, his ideas are interesting. Should they be accepted in the same way as we accept that gravity exists? Probably, not. And languages has their limitations, like our bodies have them. But the concept "there are no concepts in a person's mind" is ridiculous. If this statement is not produced by a concept then how is it different from a string of random symbols? There is nothing linguistic to share or not to share, but langauge merely serves the purpose of sharing other things.

Comment: @rus9384 The question is about Wittgenstein's conception.  "Concept in a mind" is a confused way of talking about something else, with unhelpful associations to a thing in a container. As always, reading is recommended.

Comment: @Conifold You seem to misunderstand what I want to say when I use the word "concept". Concepts to qualia are like aristotelian common sense to senses. So, they are something close to qualia, maybe a subset of them. This usage of the word "concept" differs from that of Wittgenstein's. But I don't have to use it in the same sense. And the question does not ask to answer it within Wittgenstein's philosophy.

Comment: @Conifold The "fluidity of words" itself indicates a transactional process, which in turn indicate that there should be different parties to the process. The "language game" needs unique "players" (which can be groups or generations) - Thanks for pointing out how muddled my attributions are. To clarify, Wittgenstein is more of an example than the subject of the question, my interest is in the idea that "private language is impossible".

Answer (score 1):

Sappir-Wharf has basically no academic credibility.

Wittgenstein argued that in so far as a system of symbols is private, they are not part of a language. Language is public, community use of symbols. This is built up from a picture theory of language, from an attempt to share mental models. For a mutation of a language to 'take', it is not the 1st initiation of that change that matters, but it being taken up by the community.

Qualia are pretty suspect in this view. Synaesthesia is an interesting case, with for instance high functioning mathematical savantism seems to be related to a kind of applied synaesthesia for memorising number properties and connections. In music or poetry, what is heard or the message taken away, often have very little to do with the artists intentions or mind during the creative process, yet things are still communicated, both intentionally and unintentionally - great songs frequently allow a multitude of readings to be projected.

Wittgenstein saw language as developing from a process of game playing, and that languages aren't fixed sets of symbols, but emergent sets of language-games. Each participant offers up behaviours, and people either engage back or not, iterate, alter. And various language-games are more or less formal. This is a way more flexible and versatile model, able to accomodate for instance people from entirely different cultures or species never in contact attempt to begin communication using gestures and body language.

Comment: So if private symbols are not language, does this mean Wittgenstein believed that language is not the primary modus of thought? Also I would argue that the very fluidity of language indicates that individuals have different interpretations of common language semantics, therefore there need be a private language that is (slightly) different from the _standard_ interpretation.

Comment: @christo183 There is some dispute about exactly what Wittgenstein said,  and this area is an extremely live topic of philosophy, with many polarised camps. Wittgenstein seems innsome ways to have avoided precisely aligning with any major camps, especially because hus later work is so elusive in implication and seemingly contradicts earlier ideas. An overview https://www.jstor.org/stable/2998422?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @christo183 For people advicating somr levrlnog 'intrinsic' language  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_and_thought#Scientific_hypotheses Also see mathematical subitism

Comment: Regarding the Sapir–Whorf hypothesis, I should think it more likely that the framing relationship between thought and language would be bi-directional. Growing up with an absolute spacial referencing language may lead one to develop enhanced spacial awareness; while living in the Arctic may lead to the invention of many words for "snow".

Comment: @christo183 Without language learning you get wolf-children, who never fully develop mentally or linguistically. I think Witgenstein woukd draw attention to a communitues shared modes of life as conditioning, rather than words thenselves. A quick overview of S-W hypothesis: https://www.theguardian.com/education/2014/jan/29/how-words-influence-thought

Comment: People invent new words (phrases, concepts, symbols...) all the time, some of these become mainstream, some disappear. Taken over time Language seem to change smoothly, but still there must be a minimum increment or step that must be propagated in order to start a new development in a language. The reasonable choice for such a minimum is individual thoughts and inter person interaction. Thus the quantum of language is the individual.

Comment: @christo183 No, you said it yourself, it's interaction. At the level of individual you just have a Chinese Room.

Answer (score 1):

Since Wittgenstein's anti-private language argument no longer attracts the interest it once did, the literature on it tends not to be terribly recent. The following may be of some help, however :

Owen Roger Jones, The Private Language Argument (Controversies in Philosophy), ISBN 10: 0333105109 / ISBN 13: 9780333105108
Published by Macmillan / St Martin's Press, 1971.

Warren B. Smerud, Can There be a Private Language?: An Examination of Some Principal Arguments, published by Mouton & Co., The Hague, The Netherlands, 1970.